# lookup with ObjectId works incorrect

Tags: node.js, aggregate, lookup

I have 2 collections in mongodb

1. Properties collection

   ```
   {
        "_id": "5b45b9612b33c41c3cdcc00c",
        "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
   },
   {
        "_id": "5b5844644a866c2640dcc50b",
        "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
   }
   ```
2. Communities collection

   ```
   {     
        "_id": ObjectId("5b4362e9859935243868edca"),
        "userId": "5b4329cbc5a2582294326b3b",
   }
   {
        "_id": ObjectId("5b436da8859935243868edcc"),
        "userId": "5b432f0ac5a2582294326b3d",
   }
   {
        "_id": ObjectId("5b5add46acf74732d81e9273"),
        "userId": "5b47094a28409e26d0bf0657",
   }
   ```

And I want join them by commId in properties and _id in cimmunities

```
let result = await Properties.aggregate([
                        {
                            $lookup: {
                                from: 'communities',
                                localField: 'Object(commId)',   
                                foreignField: 'ObjectId(_id)',
                                as: 'author'
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            $unwind: '$author',
                        },
                        {
                            $project: {
                                commId: 1,
                                author: {
                                    'commId': '$author._id',
                                    'userId': '$author.userId'
                                }
                            }
                        },
                    ])
```

In response has to be only 2 properties, but they duplicat...

Answer (score 0):

RESPONSE

> ```
> [
>     {
>         "_id": "5b45b9612b33c41c3cdcc00c",
>         "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
>         "author": {
>             "commId": "5b4362e9859935243868edca",
>             "userId": "5b4329cbc5a2582294326b3b"
>         }
>     },
>     {
>         "_id": "5b45b9612b33c41c3cdcc00c",
>         "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
>         "author": {
>             "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
>             "userId": "5b432f0ac5a2582294326b3d"
>         }
>     },
>     {
>         "_id": "5b45b9612b33c41c3cdcc00c",
>         "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
>         "author": {
>             "commId": "5b5add46acf74732d81e9273",
>             "userId": "5b47094a28409e26d0bf0657"
>         }
>     },
>     {
>         "_id": "5b5844644a866c2640dcc50b",
>         "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
>         "author": {
>             "commId": "5b4362e9859935243868edca",
>             "userId": "5b4329cbc5a2582294326b3b"
>         }
>     },
>     {
>         "_id": "5b5844644a866c2640dcc50b",
>         "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
>         "author": {
>             "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
>             "userId": "5b432f0ac5a2582294326b3d"
>         }
>     },
>     {
>         "_id": "5b5844644a866c2640dcc50b",
>         "commId": "5b436da8859935243868edcc",
>         "author": {
>             "commId": "5b5add46acf74732d81e9273",
>             "userId": "5b47094a28409e26d0bf0657"
>         }
>     }
> ]
> ```